# LaTeX Author setting

Tags: author, authorindex

I would like the author settings in LaTeX to be in the following format

```
Author 1.          Author2
Author1 email.   Author2 email
       A1 and A2 University

      Author 3
    Author 3 email
    Author 3 university
```

Stuck on how to get it done. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You may be over-thinking the issue. Unless there's something absolutely vital in not repeating the "A1 and A2 University" line for both author 1 and auhor 2, your readers will likely not care one bit for your formatting-related efforts. Unless the "A1 and A2 University" string is unusually long, there seems to be no harm done in repeating the line under both the Author 1 block and the Author 2 block.

Comment: So A1 and A2 are from the same university and I would like that to be written once as there is also the department and address that needs to be written.

Comment: I fully understand the setup. Other than to save a bit of space, is there a compelling reason for not simply stating the information separately for each author? E.g., do your *readers* really need to be told that the Authors 1 and 2 have the same, shared affiliation?

Comment: I just want it that, so if you can help that will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally such possibilities are given by a class. Because you are sugessting a class-independent solution, it may be done in a manual way:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

    \begin{document}
  {\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll} 
     Author 1.     &     Author2 \\
Author1 email. &  Author2 email \\
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{ A1 and A2 University}\\[12pt]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Author 3}\\
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Author 3 email}\\
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{   Author 3 university}
    \end{tabular}
}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Certainly, you can make your formatting (size, font) in the tabular. If it will be printed locally it is not a problem, but please remember that it may unexpected by a journal.